# VBA finding if value is in values

Tags: vba

I have a value `y`, and I want to find out if that value is inside this set of values : `x1, x2, ... xn`.

I can do it like this:

```
if(y = x1 or y = x2 or .....)
```

But is there a nicer way? pseudocode:

```
if(y in (x1, x2, ...., xn))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a helper function like this one:

```
Public Function FindValue(ByVal ValueToFind As Variant, ParamArray SearchIn() As Variant)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(SearchIn)
        If SearchIn(i) = ValueToFind Then
            FindValue = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

The second parameter (the `ParamArray`) is an array, so you can actually pass an indefinite number of parameters.

So you can just pass all your values to this function - the one you want to find first, and after that all the ones you want to search in:

```
Dim Found As Boolean

Found = FindValue(y, x1, x2, x3, xn)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Select Case in the same manner of (if then else):

```
Select Case Y
       Case X1, X2, X3, ...
            Do if True
       Case Else
            Do if False
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrays:

```
dim x(10)

x(1)=....
x(2)=....

y=....

for i=1 to 10
    if x(i)=y then
         ....
    end if
next i
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yet another way**

Do you have access to MS-Access 2000+?
If so add the Access Objects library reference and you will be able to use Eval function:

```
result = Eval("'y' IN ('x1', 'x2', '...' 'xn')")
```

It evaluates string expressions. Some of the SQL operators like the `IN` can be used.
See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa159060%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Pick a delimiter that won't exist in any of the values (e.g. pipe "|") and you can do it one line. If x1 represent string literals, you can use:

```
If "|x1|x2|...|xn|" Like "*|" & y & "|*" Then
```

if x1 represent variables, you can use:

```
If "|" & x1 & "|" & x2 & "|" ... & "|" & xn & "|" Like "*|" & y & "|*" Then
```

Comment: x1, x2, x3 etc look like variables, so you'll have add them to the string like `"|"+x1+"|"+x2` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
dim values as string
values = "1,2,3,4,5,"  'Note that comma is a separator and added towards the end as well.

dim lookupValue as string
lookupValue = ",4,"

dim found as Boolean
found = (instr(1, values, lookupValue) <> 0)

if found then


end if
```

EDIT: Another way

```
dim lookupValue as long
lookupValue = 21000

dim values
set values = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

with values
   .Add 1, 1
   .Add 10, 1
   .Add 100, 1
   .Add 1000, 1
   .Add 10000, 1
end with

dim found as Boolean
found = values.Exists(lookupValue)
```

Comment: They're looking for values in variables, not a string. If you wanted to check a string, it would be easier to use InStr

Comment: @BryanH: The value I am looking for in the code above is 21000 from the list of 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 . Where am I doing string comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy idea to check if the value exist is to use `Match` function:

```
Dim myTBL As Variant
    myTBL = Array(20, 30, 40, 50, 60)

'if value '30' exists in array than the position (which is >0) will be returned
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(30, myTBL, 0)
```

The only problem is that if the value doesn't exist the Match function returns an error. Therefore you should use error handling technique.

That could look like for non existing value '70':

```
'if doesn't exists error would be returned
On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(70, myTBL, 0)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Debug.Print "not exists"
    Err.Clear
End If
```

Unfortunately, that will work only in Excel.