# IN Function for Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

Is there a function in Access VBA that works like the `IN` function in SQL?
I'm looking for something like:

```
if StringValue IN(strA, strB, strC) Then
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA finding if value is in values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464144/vba-finding-if-value-is-in-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While sgedded's answer is correct, here's another way that I think is a little cleaner code.

```
Select Case stringValue 
    Case strA, strB, strC
        'is true statements
End Select
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278665(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `Instr` function:

```
If Instr("," & strA & "," & strB & "," & strC & ",", "," & stringValue & ",") > 0 Then
```

This places commas around each element to make sure the search is exact.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/instr-function-HA001228857.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here, where I used a custom helper function:
[VBA finding if value is in values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464144/vba-finding-if-value-is-in-values/15464412#15464412)

With my helper function from this answer, you can do this:

```
If FindValue(StringValue, strA, strB, strC) Then
    'value was found
Else
    'value was not found
End If
```